# Would dropping X altogether hurt?

Tags: linux, emacs, console, xorg, slackware

I live in the linux terminal all the time under my slackware GNU/linux system (an EeePC). By default, GNU Emacs won't start if It can't find several Xorg libraries. Assuming I will never use X software at all, would it make sense for me to drop all this Xorg stuff and compile emacs again ?

Are you aware of anything that could get me into troubles or making GNU Emacs not working at all ? Are there any advantage for me to keep all these dependencies ?

I am asking since as said, my main box is an eeepc with little storage and I am dangerously hitting the limits ;-)

At the very least, what would be smallest and minimal Xorg libraries one should keep to launch xterm (with a deported display) ?

Regards

Comment: Your main box is an EeePC? That's halfway between masochistic and hardcore. Kudos.

Comment: You'd be surprised how good a little eeepc is for linux + dev work.  Light, tiny and nimbile I used it as my main development PC for a year while I commuted to work.

Comment: I am pretty satisfied working with this for almost 2 years now. I principaly develop and administer RDBMS thus connecting onto other hardware most of the time. At home, to work with *lisp or erlang is arguably enough powerful :)

Comment: I'd developed my startup's first product, in Common Lisp on an Eee 701, during one winter sabbatical, but that's a mile away from using an EeePC as The Main Box....

Comment: The awesomeness of this question directs my hand to the upvote button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs is pretty easy to build, though you might have to spend some time getting the build options right.  The included INSTALL file is pretty good.

Since it's mainly a text-based tool, Emacs works well in a console.  (Who uses the silly toobar anyway?!)  And the menu bar's main advantages are for discovering the features of newly installed libraries and for printing.  But you can even access that from a tty with M-x tmm-menubar.

Having said that, you do have to reckon with the loss of a few key combinations which some Emacs packages make default use of.  For example, one of the great reasons to use Emacs these days is [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/), which makes heavy use of modifier keys + arrows to manipulate outline structures.  In a Linux console, some of these are take for other purposes, so you have to live with a few [workarounds](http://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-keys.html).  I've seen other convenience packages (for moving around visible windows, for example), that also use those keys.

Good luck.

Comment: I know how easy it is to build emacs what I was not really sure about was the impact not to build X support in it. As of org-mode, I do not use it; I did use it but it's way too much for my needs and second, I do not like all "the syntaxic sugar" one has to type.

Comment: Another thing you may have to reckon with is copying text from other applications. But good old gpm is still your friend there.  As you probably know, you can try before you buy with 'emacs -nw.' Using that in X or just running your existing emacs in the linux console will tell you whether console Emacs meets your own needs.  Also, what's a 'deported' display?

Comment: In fact, as said before, I am only using the linux console and I even did not install Xorg though emacs shipped with my slackware needs X libraries. A 'deported display', sorry if it is bad terminology, means I have to export DISPLAY variable onto another computer (export DISPLAY=foo.bar:0.0 for example).

Answer (score 5):

You should be fine building an Emacs without X as long as you're happy having it locked up inside a terminal.

On several (remote) machines I work on, I've always installed/built Emacs without X-Windows for similar reasons.

Comment: Stupid additionnal question: is a build without X smaller (in size) than a "complete" build ?

Comment: I *think* it is but I haven't got a machine around that I can verify this assumption on.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're happy living without the mouse, there is **no disadvantage** to using Emacs as a terminal-only editor.  And I see no advantage to having it loaded if you're not using it.

If you were using a more sophisticated Linux distribution, such as Debian, you could install something like `emacs23-nox` and get Emacs compiled without linking to *any* X library.  You might see if Slackware provides a similar package.  Or if the `alien` tool can convert the Debian package.  Or as a last resort, change distros.

If Slackware doesn't provide a suitable package, you certainly have grounds for requesting one.

(Having said all that, I probably would find that the best use of my time is just to live with whatever version of Emacs my distro provides.)

Comment: slackware does provide an emacs binary without X support but it is packaged with all sort of binaries: with X, etc. It's slackware after all ;) What I just need is to edit/to patch the slackbuild and package a nox version. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well... I'm usually using `vim`... ;-)

I usually install Debian's `vim-nox` package which is simply `vim` compiled with everything except GUI; I do that even on my workstations, where I do have full GNOME environment. I simply like the way `vim` works in the same terminal window I do other things.

When I tried `emacs` some time ago, the first thing I changed was to disable its GUI; I don't actually know how much did I lose, because I didn't know `emacs` very well--still I found no essential functionality removed.

You should try. You can always go back to the standard compilation.

Comment: I will try for sure but before spending time and burning my CPU, I just need to be sure it won't hurt anything (it should not but I am kind of pessimistic by nature ;-))

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mg_%28editor%29 .